# Azure Devops branches commits

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, devops

I have a 'main' branch and one 'dev' branch. After I create a PR and merge dev into main, the branches tab shows '1 Behind' and '1 Ahead', and for each merge one number increments on both 'Behind' and 'Ahead' in dev branch. But the content from files remains the same from both the branches. These numbers are misleading, It shouldn't be same like '0 Behind' and '0 Ahead'? Or Is it necessary to always delete the 'dev' branch after each successful merge. Please help me to understand this. [image: Branches tab sample]

Comment: What merge method are you using when completing your PRs? If you are squash merging, then yes, you are going to get a **new** commit.

Comment: Yes, I am using squash merge only.  Let me try the other merge types too. Thank you @DanielMann for pointing me in right direction.